# Observable nested with loop

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I want to create a nested observable to save one content with tag related. First to save content and return content id to save tag with content id as foreign key by the way look like the service send data as the same time in my loop. (backend log run pararel) how can I make it wait until done to do next one

component.ts

```
save(){
  this.contentService.savecontent(this.content_input) // save content
     .subscribe(
     data => { this.listContentData = data }, // return data to get content id
     error => { error = error },
     () => {
        this.savetag(this.listContentData); // save tag
     });
}

savetag(listcontentdata): void {
   // listdraftCategories is a list of tag
    for (var i = 0; i < this.listdraftCategories.length; i++) {  
        this.tagService.savetagwithcontent(this.listdraftCategories[i], listcontentdata)
            .subscribe(
            data => { data = data },
            error => { },
            () => {
            });
    }
}
```

service.ts

```
savecontent(contentObj: any): Observable<any> {

    contentObj = JSON.parse(contentObj);

    let body = JSON.stringify(

        {
            "token": "test",
            "content": {
                "contentName": contentObj.itemName // contentId will be autoincrement in backend
                }
            }
        }
    );

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.host + this.url_content + this.url_save, body, options)
        .map(res => this.extractData(res))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

savetagwithcontent(tagObj: any, contentObj: any): Observable<any> {

    console.log("obj", contentObj);

    let body = JSON.stringify(
        {
            "token": "test",
            "content": {

                "fkTag": {
                    "tagId": tagObj.tagId
                },
                "fkContent": {
                    "contentId": contentObj.responseObject[0].contentId
                }

            }
        }
    );

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.host + this.url_tag_has_content + this.url_save, body, options)
        .map(res => this.extractData(res))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

backend log (save tag with content)

```
--- start save tag with content ---
--- start save tag with content ---
--- content id : 1 tag id: 1 ---
--- content id : 1 tag id: 2 ---
--- end save tag with content ---
--- end save tag with content ---
```

look like it went in method at the almost same time. how can I manage to make savetag wait for one save complete then do next one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it would be using a recursive method:

```
savetag(listcontentdata:any, index = 0): void {
    if(index >= this.listdraftCategories.length){
        return;
    }
    // listdraftCategories is a list of tag
    this.tagService.savetagwithcontent(this.listdraftCategories[index], listcontentdata)
        .subscribe(
        data => { 
            data = data;
            this.savetag(listcontentdata, index +1);
        },
        error => { },
        () => {
        });

}
```

This way, the next iteration of your `savetag` method will only start once the current one the `observable` finished its operation.

Comment: your code it's work but I need to prevent it from do more than length by add if(index < this.listdraftCategories.length) thank you. :-)

Comment: oh yes sorry I made the example to show you how I would add a recursive method, let me fix this error.

Comment: what if I have other tag list how can I manage it with the same method ? (something like listdraftIndustries , listdraftCompany how can I save from savetag method if it's not the same list I can't use same index right?)

Comment: I think that if you have two lists, you should use two functions and call them once in a third one, then they'll carry their own index and they will be independant from each other.

Comment: something like this ?      () => {  this.callsavetag(); } and in callsavetag(); has method savecategories(), savecompany(), saveetc()

Comment: yes, this way each method will have its own index, because using the same index is very dangerous if one of your arrays is shorter than the other ones.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
const observables = [];
for (var i = 0; i < this.listdraftCategories.length; i++) {  
  observables.push(this.tagService.savetagwithcontent(this.listdraftCategories[i], listcontentdata));
}

let i = 0;
let finished = true;
while(i < observables.length) {
  if (finished) {
    finished = false;
    observables[i].subscribe(
      data => {
        finished = true;
        i++;
        data = data 
      },
      error => { },
      () => {});
  }
}
```

There could be some nifty rxjs operator however I don't know it.

You could also change your design a little bit. You could send to backend endpoint all tags for given category and handle saving tags there. You would have full control of how you want to save them.

Comment: yeah I think something like that too but too bad service already write and I have no authorize to edit it. :(

Comment: damn it :). What about the while loop?

Comment: I got infinite loop now while I console.log(i) I try log observables.length and it return 0 while I log observables I see observe array

Comment: my bad it return true tag length but in the loop it run console.log(i) infinite.

Comment: hmm..., I run this in my code and I don't have infinite loop. the only difference is how I create observable because I don't have your service     const observables: any[] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      observables.push(Observable.from([j]));
    }